# Доступ к Windows Form из другой формы

Tags: c#, winforms

Две формы (form1, form2), 2 класса, в первом

```
private void bntSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 form1 = new Form1();
        form1.openWebPhoto();
    }
```

во втором

```
public void openWebPhoto()
    {
        file = Image.FromFile("picture.png");
        pictureBox1.Image = file;
        opened = true;
    }
```

если вызывать из второго класса openWebPhoto(), то есть из текущего окна, в котором прописан метод, то все работает, но нужно получить доступ из другого окна и это не получается, ошибок не выдает

Answer (score 0):

```
private void bntSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 form1 = new Form1();
    var image = form1.openWebPhoto();
}

public Image openWebPhoto()
{
    file = Image.FromFile("picture.png");
    pictureBox1.Image = file;
    opened = true;
    return file;
}
```

Теперь в image, в 1 классе находится ваша картинка.